# How to create Rust ndarray with custom explicit indices

Tags: arrays, rust, rust-ndarray

Is it possible in Rust to create and initialise a 3D array (`ndarray`) with explicit indices? As I understand, by default Rust creates an array with zero-based indexing:

```
use ndarray::Array3;
...
const NX: usize = 100;
const NY: usize = 100;
const NZ: usize = 100;

let mut arr = Array3::<f32>::zeros((NX, NY, NZ));
```

This will create an array with indices running from 0 to 99. I would like to create an array with indices from 1 to 100. The below construct is not valid Rust code, but would be most welcome:

```
let mut arr = Array3::<f32>::zeros((1..100, 1..100, 1..100));
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Rust?

P.S. There are many stones being thrown at Fortran. But multidimensional arrays and indexing is what Fortran excels at!

**Update:**
Custom indices would be extremely useful for some applied mathematics codes to cover boundary case calculations, e.g. a 3D array with only two planes next to the boundary:

```
let mut arr = Array3::<f32>::zeros((IMIN..IMAX, JMIN..JMAX, KMAX-1..KMAX));
```

Comment: Even if there would be a way to do that (which I don't think, not without your own crate), don't do that. Your code will look weird and confusing. And zero-based indexing has performance advantage, at least in language not planned for one-based indexing.